# Marshall map into <key>value</key> failed

Tags: java, jaxb2

I use JDK7 and Jaxb

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to marshall a map as follow:

```
<options>
  <key> VALUE </key>
  <key2> VALUE2 </key2>
 ...
</options>
```

So I try this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Preferences {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionsMapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, String> options;
}



public class OptionsMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<OptionsMapAdapter.OptionsWrapper, Map<String, String>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(final OptionsWrapper value) throws Exception {
        final Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
        for (JAXBElement<String> option : value.options) {
            options.put(option.getName().toString(), option.getValue());
        }
        return options;
    }

    @Override
    public OptionsWrapper marshal(final Map<String, String> value) throws Exception {
        OptionsWrapper wrapper = new OptionsWrapper();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> property : value.entrySet()) {
            wrapper.options.add(new JAXBElement<>(
                    new QName(property.getKey()),
                    String.class, property.getValue()));
        }
        return wrapper;
    }

    static class OptionsWrapper {
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        public List<JAXBElement<String>> options = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

It works fine on **marshall** but fail on **unmarshall** with error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

On debug I see that on OptionsMapAdapter#unmarshal the OptionsWrapper.options list doesn't contains list of JAXBElement but list of com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.

Is it a bug, how to correct the problem (without untyping the list options) ?
With lax or without lax there is the same problem.

Comment: Marshalling a map of string-string and unmarshalling the resulting `OptionsWrapper` works fine for me on `jdk 1.7.0_67` with your code.

Comment: @mystarrocks Using 1.8.0_20, the Map returned in Preferences is empty and OptionsMapAdapter.unmarshal is never called. mystar, did you check that the map is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

This modified variant of the adapter works for marshalling and unmarshalling (1.8.0_20).

```
public class OptionsMapAdapter 
  extends XmlAdapter<OptionsMapAdapter.OptionsWrapper, Map<String, String>> {
  static Document document;
  static {
    try { document = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
      } catch( Exception e ){
        // error handling
      }
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, String> unmarshal(final OptionsWrapper value) throws Exception {
    final Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    for (Element option : value.options) {
        options.put(option.getTagName(), option.getTextContent());
    }
    return options;
  }

  @Override
  public OptionsWrapper marshal(final Map<String, String> value) throws Exception {
    OptionsWrapper wrapper = new OptionsWrapper();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> property : value.entrySet()) {
      Element element = document.createElement(property.getKey() );
      element.setTextContent( property.getValue() );
      wrapper.options.add( element );
    }
    return wrapper;
  }

  static class OptionsWrapper {
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public List<Element> options = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

`org.w3c.dom.Element` is a little less convenient than JAXBElement, but it affects but the adapter.